# Java replaceALL for string

Tags: java, string, replaceall

I have a string:

```
100-200-300-400
```

i want replace the dash to "," and add single quote so it become:

```
 '100','200','300','400'
```

My current code only able to replace "-" to ","  ,How can i plus the single quote?

```
String str1 = "100-200-300-400";      
split = str1 .replaceAll("-", ",");

if (split.endsWith(",")) 
{
   split = split.substring(0, split.length()-1);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
split = str1 .replaceAll("-", "','");
split = "'" + split + "'";
```

Comment: that will only quote whole string into 1 single quote,  '100,200,300,400'

Comment: @user3172596 I tested it and got `'100','200','300','400'`. The `replaceAll` call adds the remaining single quotes. Note that it's not the same `replaceAll` call as in your question.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative if you are using java 1.8 then you could create a [StringJoiner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html) and split the String by `-`. This would be a bit less time efficient, but it would be more safe if you take, for example, a traling `-` into account.

A small sample could look like this.

```
String string = "100-200-300-400-";
String[] splittet = string.split("-");
StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner("','", "'", "'");
for(String s : splittet) {
    joiner.add(s);
}
System.out.println(joiner);
```

Comment: is there any solution for java 1.6? not using java 1.8

Comment: @user3172596 it isn´t included inside the 1.6 jdk sadly. You´d need to go for regex otherwise. The solution provided by Eran should work.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String s = "100-200-300-400";
    System.out.println(s.replaceAll("(\\d+)(-|$)", "'$1',").replaceAll(",$", ""));
}
```

O/P :

```
'100','200','300','400'
```

Or (if you don't want to use `replaceAll()` twice.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String s = "100-200-300-400";
    s = s.replaceAll("(\\d+)(-|$)", "'$1',");
    System.out.println(s.substring(0, s.length()-1));
}
```

Comment: is ur regex limited to only integer? my value might be:
***-100-TSK-534

Comment: @user3172596 - You can replace `\\d+` with `[a-zA-Z]+` if you have values like `abc-asa` etc